# (System)verilog macro containing a comment?

Tags: macros, comments, verilog, system-verilog

Is there any way in verilog to write a macro containing a comment so the comment will be 'instantiated' in every instance of the macro? I need the comment inside the macro to turn off a lint complaint about the other code in the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use block comments (`/* */`) and probable multi-line macros. Example:

```
`define macro_with_comment \
  /* your comment here */ \
  macro_body_here \
  /* another your comment here */ \
  another_line
```

Be warned, macros are a pain to debug is something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The use of comments pragmas for tools is discouraged. The (System)Verilog LRM is not very clear about the use of comments in macro processing. It is clear that single line comments (preceded with `//` are not part of the expanded text, but makes no mention about `/* mult-line */` comments. Most pre-processors remove all comments before expandint text.

Verilog-2001 added attributes `(* text *)` to the language, but people are still not aware that they should be using them instead of comments.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the following syntax that worked for me with a similar issue:

```
`define macro_with_comment(SLASH_CHAR=/) \
    ``SLASH_CHAR``SLASH_CHAR <write your comment here> \
     macro body here \
    ``SLASH_CHAR``SLASH_CHAR <write your comment here> \
     macro body here...
```

Comment: amirros , would you like an answer to your question? Please [edit] according to [answer] - or delete this, if you do not mean this as an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).